# Как сохранить только одну форму в админке Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

В админке выводится модель Event и связанная с ней по Fk модель Post

```
    class EventPostInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Post
    extra = 1
    fields = ('title', 'post_type', 'img', 'pub_date', 'body', 'share', 'status', 'slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'status', 'release_date', 'location', 'bonus', 'descript', 'slug')
    inlines = [
        EventPostInline,
    ]
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

Суть в том чтобы сделать так что зайдя в раздел Event можно посмотреть связанные посты и создать следующий связанный пост. Но в этом случае становится невозможным создать Event без Post. Можно ли решить эту проблему стандартными средствами, не прибегая к написанию собственной админки.

Comment: а что именно вам мешает создать объект Event, не добавляя к нему объекты Post?

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в класс `EventPostInline` атрибут `min_num = 0`, который указывает на минимальное допустимое количество связанных объектов.

Ссылка на документацию Django: [min_num](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.min_num)